# c# Linq remove one Item

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List which contains Objects. One Property of the object is from type date and I would like to group by date and remove the item, if a group hold only one item.

My list is already sorted by date:

```
01.01.2018
01.01.2018
02.01.2018 <- this one should be removed
03.01.2018
03.01.2018
```

My linq method looks like this:

```
var listCleaned = myList.GroupBy(x => x.WHEN.ToShortDateString())
                        .TakeWhile(y => y.Count() > 1)
                        .SelectMany(i => i.ToList())
                        .ToList();
```

My Problem with this is, that every item after 02.01.2018 are removed also.

Comment: Side note: The `ToList()` inside `SelectMany` is not needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of `TakeWhile`, use `Where`:

```
var listCleaned = myList.GroupBy(x => x.WHEN.Date)
                        .Where(y => y.Count() > 1)
                        .SelectMany(i => i.ToList())
                        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try another approach:-

> Here I `Where()`I have added condition that only select those object whose `WHEN`date occurs more than once in `collection`

```
var listCleaned = myList.Where(x => myList.Where(ele => ele.WHEN.Date == x.WHEN.Date).Count > 1).ToList();
```